# How to access LAN from a wireless connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have 2 Windows 10 PCs with which I'd like to play games such as Age of Empires 2 or Cossacks in LAN. They are both on the same private network, one of them uses wireless.
They have IP 192.168.0.13 and 192.168.0.18 respectively, and I can ping one from the other.
I added the apps in Windows defender (even tried to completely disable the firewall).
When I open the game, I create a new game from the wired computer, then I try to join from the second computer but I cannot see the game I want to join. The inverse doesn't work neither.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Make sure the Network cards are both set to Private and not Public.  Make sure Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing (Advanced Network Settings) have both been set ON.  It is helpful if both computers use the same Microsoft Account to log on.

Comment: @John yes the configuration is set as you said

Comment: The game probably wants to use the computer name in its setup. Make sure the HOSTS file in both machines allows the other machine.   An entry like  192.168.1.1  computer_name   ..  Restart after setting up the HOSTS file.  You need to start up Notepad as Administrator to edit and save the HOSTS file

Comment: Buggy Wi-Fi implementations often break multicast, which breaks service-discovery protocols, like how some LAN games find local game hosts. One common trigger for multicast-breaking bugs is trying to handle old WPA (TKIP) support on a WPA2 (AES-CCMP) network. So make sure your wireless router has original WPA (TKIP) completely disabled.

Comment: @John I tried this but it did not work, I added in each file the IP adress and the name of the other computer

Comment: @Spiff if I do this I loose wifi access, I don't see the network on my laptop

Comment: On one computer:   NET USE  X:  \\IPofothermachine\somefolder.   What numerical error do you get?

Comment: @John I tried net use X: \\192.168.0.13\c from the laptop and got error 53 "the network path was not found". I also tried with a public folder instead of c and got the same

Comment: System Error 53 is Network Connection not found. So it is fairly basic (that is, nothing is working so forget the fine points further along). Trying to map just C  won't work. Make a folder c:\temp on the target machine and make sure "Everyone" has permission to it. Then on the source machine, type:    NET USE X: \\192.168.0.13\temp   Does this work?

Comment: When doing what you propose, I get error 67: network name not found. I tried with Warcraft3 and it works properly. I also used a more recent version of age of empires. In that case, it seems that the game considers both PCs have the same IP and assign them the same name: the name of one of the two windows users. One can see the game created by the other PC, but trying to access it does not work.